Using jaxws-maven-plugin with multiple wsdl files with the same portType
I use com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-maven-plugin plugin in a spring project, the configuration specifies only links to wsdl files
I process several wsdl files, two of them use the same targetNamespace and portType. Because of which the plugin overwrites the package and web service interface.
I tried to configure jaxws.xml this way, but I get an error related to the lack of portType in one or another wsdl
<bindings xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxws">

    <bindings node="wsdl:definitions/wsdl:portType[@name='Client1']">
        <class name="Client1WebService"/>
    </bindings>

    <bindings node="wsdl:definitions/wsdl:portType[@name='Client2']">
        <class name="Client2WebService"/>
    </bindings>

</bindings>

I have reached a dead end in solving this problem. Please help.
